# R functions that pass on unevaluated arguments to other functions

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm still trying to understand lazy evaluation in R.  Here's something that confuses me:

```
f=function(x) as.character(substitute(x))
g=function(...) f(...)
h=function(z) f(z)

f(y)
# [1] "y"
g(y)
# [1] "y"
h(y)
# [1] "z"
```

Why do `g` and `h` not behave the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lazy Evaluation aspect of `R` is that it does not evaluate an object until it is needed.  However, what you are seeing has little to do with lazy evaluation. Rather it is related to the ellipsis argument:

When calling `g(y)`, `f` is substituting the value of x with the ellipsis.  But `substitute(...)` essentially substitutes in the value sent to the ellipsis (in this context, the ellipsis act *similar* [not exactly] to another call to substitute).

When calling `h(y)`,  again `f` is substituting the value of  `x`, which is a value other than ellipses, namely `z` and so substitutes in that value.

---

### Edit as per @Alexander's comment:

Please have a look at the following and execute in your environment.

```
f=function(x) {cat("\nHERE IS THE OUTPUT FOR `f`: "); as.character(substitute(x))}
g=function(...) {cat("I am evaluating the first argument", ..1, "\n"); f(...)}
h=function(z)  {print(z); f(z)}

y <- "Look, I am evaluated!\n"
f(y)
g(y)
h(y)
```

Comment: What helped me understand this was to ask myself "What is the expression bound to the promise for the formal argument in `f`?" In the last case it is clearly `z`, while in the second, `y` is passed on unchanged via `...`.

Comment: @Joran, nice way to look at it.  Thanks for sharing that, I'm sure I'll be using that thought process next time I'm debugging

Comment: The lazy evaluation part is that `y` never gets evaluated!  I'm still not clear on why `h` doesn't substitute `y` for `z` before calling `f`.

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz, please see the edit.  Lazy evaluation is occurring (as it occurs everywhere in `R`) but it has little to do with what you are seeing.  Rather, it is related to the `ellipsis` and how it has handled

Comment: With regards to "_I'm still not clear on why h doesn't substitute y for z before calling f_"  Why **would** this happen?

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz `substitute` is evaluating `x` in the current environment. In that context, that is inside the function call `f(x = z)`. When that function call happened, a promise was created that bound the expression `z` to the argument `x`. If we actually needed the value of `x`, R would reach back and find `z`, and then evaluate _that_ promise and look in `y`. But as it is, you are simply asking R to report what symbol was bound to `x` for the current function call.