# Unevaluated argument in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I still a novice in R, and still understanding lazy evaluation. I read quite a few threads on SO ([R functions that pass on unevaluated arguments to other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049248/r-functions-that-pass-on-unevaluated-arguments-to-other-functions)), but I am still not sure.

**Question 1:**

Here's my code:

```
f <- function(x = ls()) {
  a<-1
  #x ##without x
  }
f(x=ls())
```

When I execute this code i.e. `f()`, nothing returns. Specifically, I don't see the value of `a`. Why is it so?

**Question 2:**

Moreover, I do see the value of `a` in this code:

```
f <- function(x = ls()) {
  a<-1
  x ##with x
  }
f(x=ls())
```

When I execute the function by `f()` I get :

```
[1] "a" "x"
```

Why is it so? Can someone please help me?

Comment: @BigDataSci - Thanks for your answer. Do you mind explaining this a bit? I didn't quite understand your comment.

Comment: if there is no explicit return statement, function returns last line of the execution. In first case: `z<- f()` would assign `z` a value of 1. In second case, it returns the value of x, i.e., output of `x<- ls()` which includes `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

This has nothing to do with lazy evaluation.

A function returns the result of the last statement it executed. In this case the last statement was `a <- 1`. The result of `a <- 1` is one. You could for example do `b <- a <- 1` which would result in `b` being equal to 1. So, in this case you function returns 1.

```
> f <- function(x = ls()) {
+   a<-1
+   }
> b <- f(x=ls())
> print(b)
[1] 1
```

The argument `x` is nowhere used, and so doesn't play any role.

Functions can return values visibly (the default) or invisibly. In order to return invisibly the function `invisible` can be used. An example:

```
> f1 <- function() {
+   1
+ }
> f1()
[1] 1
> 
> f2 <- function() {
+   invisible(1)
+ }
> f2()
>
```

In this case `f2` doesn't seem to return anything. However, it still returns the value 1. What the invisible does, is not print anything when the function is called and the result is not assigned to anything. The relevance to your example, is that `a <- 1` also returns invisibly. That is the reason that your function doesn't seem to return anything. But when assigned to `b` above, `b` still gets the value 1.

**Question 2**

First, I'll explain why you see the results you see. The `a` you see in your result, was caused some previous code. If we first clean the workspace, we only see `f`. This makes sense as we create a variable `f` (a function is also a variable in R) and then do a `ls()`.

```
> rm(list = ls())
> 
> f <- function(x = ls()) {
+   a<-1
+   x 
+ }
> f(x=ls())
[1] "f"
```

What the function does (at least what you would expect), if first list all variables `ls()` then pass the result to the function as `x`. This function then returns `x`, which is the list of all variables, which then gets printed.

*How this can be modified to show lazy evaluation at work*

```
> rm(list = ls())
> 
> f <- function(x) {
+   a <<- 1
+   x
+ }
> 
> f(x = ls())
[1] "a" "f"
>
```

In this case the global assignment is used (`a <<- 1`), which creates a new variable `a` in the global workspace (not something you normally want to do).

In this case, one would still expect the result of the function call to be just `f`. The fact that it also shows `a` is caused by lazy evaluation.

Without lazy evaluation, it would first evaluate `ls()` (at that time only `f` exists in the workspace), copy that into the function with the name `x`. The function then returns `x`. In this case the `ls()` is evaluated before `a` is created.

However, with lazy evaluation, the expression `ls()` is only evaluated when the result of the expression is needed. In this case that is when the function returns and the result is printed. At that time the global environment has changed (`a` is created), which means that `ls()` also shows `a`.

(This is also one of the reasons why you don't want functions to change the global workspace using `<<-`.)

Comment: Fantastic response. 2 questions: what does `a<<- 1`? **Question 1** It seems from your answer that `a` is not only assigned `1`  but is also evaluated (i.e. "used"). Correct? **Question 2** I modified your example a bit to include `b<-2` as the last statement. However, now I don't see `a` being returned at all. Code: `rm(list = ls()); f <- function(x) {a <<- 1; x; b<- 2}; c<-f(x = ls());c` Why is this happening? I'd appreciate your thoughts. If we check the value of `c`, it would show `2`. I would have expected `a` as well. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: @watchtower First question: yes, more precise: the value of `a` is returned by the function and assigned to `b`.

Comment: @watchtower Second question: when you add `b <- 2` to the function as the last statement, the result of that statement is returned by the function (same as first original question). Therefore, the function returns the value of `b` which is `2`. `x` is used in the function but not returned, therefore, `ls()` is evaluated, but the result of that is not used and not returned.